# Node.js - How to send data from html to express

Tags: html, node.js, forms, node.js-client, http-post

this is form example in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>CSS3 Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contact">
    <h1>Send an email</h1>
    <form action="/myaction" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" />

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" />

            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="Send message" />

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is node.js function that run on the server:

```
var sys = require('sys'),
    http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            switch (req.url) 
                case '/myaction':
                        res.end(?????);
                    break;
            }
    }).listen(8080);
sys.puts('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I call `myaction` function in the node.js from the html page? Because the html file runs on port 80 and node.js on 8080 (when I try to move the node.js to port 80 it writes "// Unhandled 'error' event")
2. In the node.js function where I put "?????" how can I get data from the html form.
   When I type req.html.body.name I don't get the data...

Comment: Have you thought about using express? It has a built in handler for forms.  I use it with great success posting forms.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Using `http.createServer` is very low-level and really not useful for creating web applications as-is.

A good framework to use on top of it is Express, and I would seriously suggest using it. You can install it using `npm install express`.

When you have, you can create a basic application to handle your form:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app     = express();

//Note that in version 4 of express, express.bodyParser() was
//deprecated in favor of a separate 'body-parser' module.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

//app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
  res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});
```

You can make your form point to it using:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/myaction" method="post">
```

The reason you can't run Node on port 80 is because there's already a process running on that port (which is serving your `index.html`). You could use Express to also serve static content, like `index.html`, using the `express.static` middleware.

Comment: @chotesah that's not related to the code posted here, but an issue in your app.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to expand on Obertklep's answer. In his example it is an NPM module called `body-parser` which is doing most of the work. Where he puts `req.body.name`, I believe he/she is using `body-parser` to get the contents of the name attribute(s) received when the form is submitted.

If you do not want to use Express, use `querystring` which is a built-in Node module. See the answers in the link below for an example of how to use `querystring`.

It might help to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js), which is very similar to your quest.