# html node.js form input

Tags: html, node.js

I am following this [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568851/how-i-can-send-data-from-html-form-to-node-js-function) but am receiving this error:

`usera@usera-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/test/sample$ nodejs smallNode.js 
/home/usera/Desktop/test/sample/smallNode.js:3
var app = express();
          ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/usera/Desktop/test/sample/smallNode.js:3:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3`

What am I missing?

Server side code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app     = express();

//Note that in version 4 of express, express.bodyParser() was
//deprecated in favor of a separate 'body-parser' module.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

//app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
  res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});
```

Here are the results from running npm install. It looks like there is a warning during the install process so maybe that's the issue...

```
usera@usera-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/test/sample$ npm install express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.8
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.8
npm WARN engine express@2.5.8: wanted: {"node":">= 0.4.1 < 0.7.0"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
express@2.5.8 node_modules/express
├── qs@0.4.2
├── mime@1.2.4
├── mkdirp@0.3.0
└── connect@1.9.2 (formidable@1.0.17)
```

Comment: Works fine when I test it.

Comment: did you `npm install express`?

Comment: Yes, edited original post to include results from `npm install express`

Comment: Thats an old version of express... you should at least use v3, or better v4 to have it export a function.

Comment: I guess your `package.json` has the wrong version.

Comment: So should I be trying to figure out 3.x.x/4.x.x version information for the `package.json` file or is there some other approach so I don't have to figure out what the latest greatest version is? Where can I find version information?

Comment: Got it, updated the `package.json` file to something like this: `"express": "~4.0.0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats an old version of express... you should at least use v3, or better v4 to have it export a function. – migg