# Getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token if" while parsing formdata from HTML page through nodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, node-modules

I want to use form input from HTML to JS. For that i am using following snippet but getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token if" can anyone help in modifying it.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(html_form_path, function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
    var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var qdata = q.query;
    res.write(qdata.Input());
}).listen(8080);
```

HTML FORM:

```
<html>

<body>
    <form type='get'>
        <input type="text" name='Input'>
        <input type='submit'>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try using body-parser with express. Check this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568851/node-js-how-to-send-data-from-html-to-express

Comment: you dont need fs module, you nees body-parser and express or some other framework will make it easier to receive request

Comment: The code you've shared doesn't mention `if` at all. The error message is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @TusharMudgal — It is a GET form, there is no body to parse with body-parser.

Comment: @MladenSkrbic — How are they supposed to read the file without the `fs` module? They don't need `body-parser` as there is no request body to parse. While I'd generally recommend Express, there's no major benefit to adding it in here.

Comment: The code you've provided throws the error `ReferenceError: html_form_path is not defined` not the one you say it throws. You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

You should send data from html to server, you will need bodyparser and it is easiest to do if you also have express on server then you make submit button and i form tag add action and method atributes and on server you expect

```
app.post("/action",function(req,res){
    req.body.input
})
```

html:

```
<form action='/action' method='POST'  >
    <input name=input''>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

also this will reload your page, if you want not to reload you need use ajax to send data you can use axios in javascript.
see express docs on how to set it up and you need see bodyparser docs and then use this code

Comment: "you will need bodyparser" — That's only true if the data is being POSTed … which it isn't in the code in the question.

Comment: this is not how you make get request and if it is not post request why he uses input... and also why would he use server for this anyway

Comment: "this is not how you make get request" — Yes it is. (Well…ish. The `type` attribute value is nonsense but will be ignored because it only applies to forms with `method="POST"`)

Comment: "if it is not post request why he uses input" — So that the query string contains data provided by the user of the browser.

Comment: "and also why would he use server for this anyway" — I have no idea what the OP's end goal is. The code appears to be an attempt to learn how to read query strings.

Comment: There *are* lots of problems with the code, but the basic concept of using a form to make a GET request is not one of them, and none of the problems in the code appear to be related to the problem described in the question.

Comment: this needs to be post request and then u send response back

Comment: It does not need to be a POST request. Forms are used for GET requests all the time. Type something into the Search box at the top of *this* page and press enter. It's a form. It makes a GET request. Form triggered GET requests are one of the basic building blocks of the WWW.

Comment: var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('id: ' + req.query.id);
});

app.listen(3000);

Comment: this is how he should make it