# Post method values returned null in node js

Tags: node.js, express

When submit the form the form fields value not came in post method.

here is code in index.html file

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:4000/insertion">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>E-Mail</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

in server side script code is

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(cors());

app.post('/insertion',function(request,response){
    console.log(request.body);
});

app.get('/index',function(request,response){
    response.send('hi ');
});

app.listen(4000);
```

its not showing showing any error but value is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow this... need to pass value in url function

```
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.post('/formdata',urlencodedParser,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use [bodyParser.urlencoded](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) to read the form data.

Add this and try again.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

Comment: Can you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568851/node-js-how-to-send-data-from-html-to-express) and see if it is useful

Comment: still repeat empty object {}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))` after the app.use(bodyParser.json()). You can see documentation [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.use(cors());

app.post('/insertion',function(request,response){
    console.log(request.body);
});

app.get('/index',function(request,response){
    response.send('hi ');
});

app.listen(4000);
```

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));